# Additional resources needed for standalone Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I currently run a simple PowerShell script every hour on my development Windows 2012 server. It generates a CSV file which can be downloaded via HTTP from an IIS website on the same server.

I'd prefer to move it into a cloud service and as my client currently uses Office 365 extensively, a small standalone Azure VM would be a logical choice.

I've used the price calculator for the VM but do I also need to factor in other network components? Such as a virtual network interface, virtual LAN, IP address and firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Networking tab of the pricing calculator. Any network functions more advanced than Internet *ingress* and local availability zone traffic have a price.

Also storage, for the OS disk and any data you might need to store.

Build your thing, let it run for one day, and look at the cost analysis in billing. Consider a couple designs:

- Functions, where you just supply the script and the trigger, you don't deploy infrastructure
- IaaS, your proposed VM